# Select New causing 'Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities'

Tags: c#, linq

I've set up a POCO that gets entities from the DB and returns as a VisionLine object.  I'm getting an "**Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.**" error.  It seems to be related to the setting of the Words and ClosestMatchingSelectionCollection properties.  I'm not sure how I can fix it or what alternative I have to set the values of the Words and ClosestMatchingSelectionCollection collections

```
public IQueryable<VisionLine> Get(int lineId)
        {
            return from u in db.ComputerVisionLines
                where u.lineID == lineId
                   select new VisionLine()
                   {
                       VisionLineId = u.LineID,
                       Text = u.Text
                       Words = new ObservableCollection<VisionWord>(from w in u.ComputerVisionWords.ToList()
                                                                    select new VisionWord()
                                                                    {
                                                                        Text = w.Text,
                                                                        BoundingBox = new ObservableCollection<double>(Array.ConvertAll(w.BoundingBox.Split(','), Double.Parse)),
                                                                        Confidence = w.Confidence,
                                                                        VisionWordId = w.WordID,
                                                                    }),
                       BoundingBox = new ObservableCollection<double>(Array.ConvertAll(u.BoundingBox.Split(','), Double.Parse)),
                       ClosestMatchingSelectionCollection = new ObservableCollection<VisionResult>(from r in u.ComputerVisionResults.ToList()
                                                                                                        select new VisionResult()
                                                                                                        {
                                                                                                            SelectionName = r.SelectionName,
                                                                                                            CouponId = r.CouponID,
                                                                                                            EventId = r.EventID,
                                                                                                            MarketId = r.MarketID,
                                                                                                            SelectionId = r.SelectionID,
                                                                                                            Confidence = r.Confidence
                                                                                                        })
                   };
        }
```

Comment: As far as I understand your code is being translated to SQL query, so Linq To Entities does not know how to translate `ObservableCollection` to SQL. Either try to use there plain collection (like `Words = (from ..).ToList()`) there or return `IEnumerable` from method getting results from DB via `.ToList` for example.

Comment: That was exactly the problem, changing the properties to Lists and using .ToList sorted it, thanks

Comment: Adding as an answer then)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is being translated to SQL query, so Linq To Entities does not know how to translate `ObservableCollection` to SQL. Either try to use there plain collection (like `Words = (from ..).ToList()`) there or return `IEnumerable` from method getting results from DB via `.ToList` for example.